# Image cut off on all 4 sides

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

How do I fix it so the whole image is viewable?

You can see the box-shadow is being cut out of the image on all 4 sides.

Is there a way to fix this?

The code snippet I provided shows what I am describing here.

That is the issue I am having, is there anything that will work to resolve it?

code https://jsfiddle.net/m67vLeso/

```css
.curtain {
  width: 550px;
  height: 193px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s ease;
}

.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s ease;
}

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

.curtain:hover .j1 {
  transform: translateX(-500%);
}

.curtain:hover .j2 {
  transform: translateX(500%);
}
```

```html
<div class="curtain">

  <div class="split-wrap">
    <div class="j1">
      <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
        <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
          <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
          <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
          <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="j2">
      <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
        <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
          <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
          <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
          <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add more space for your box-shadows in case you are using `overflow: hidden;`

```css
.curtain {
  width: 550px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;

}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s ease;
}

.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s ease;
}

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 20px;
  left: auto;
}

.curtain:hover .j1 {
  transform: translateX(-500%);
}

.curtain:hover .j2 {
  transform: translateX(500%);
}
```

```html
<div class="curtain">

  <div class="split-wrap">
    <div class="j1">
      <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
        <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
          <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
          <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
          <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="j2">
      <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
        <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
          <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
          <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
          <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the divs .j1 and .j2 have the property "overflow:hidden" applied. You can't remove this property because it acts as a mask.

You should add some margins or paddings in those divs and change the dimensions of the absolute positioned items accordingly.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet please so I can see what you mean?

Comment: See the @VladislavAkhmetvaliyev's answer, it seems ok.

Comment: Would yours be better?

Comment: Is the same technique. The values can be better, for example adding 30px instead of 20px and adjusting the height (there is a little cut yet on top). Check the differences between his code and yours, play with the values and find those that better fits your project.

Comment: Do you see a difference between

Code 1: https://jsfiddle.net/Lp50vfmy/

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 20px;
  left: auto;
}

/ And Code 2: https://jsfiddle.net/84r0uve3/

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 30px;
  left: -90px;
} ???

Comment: Do you see any difference at all?

Comment: Do you still see a cut in the codes I did?

Comment: "Do you still see a cut in the codes I did?" Yes, if you look your monitor from below you could see it.

Comment: What's your opinion and thoughts on doing it this way? Code: https://jsfiddle.net/g4d6vyfe/

.split-wrap {
transform: scale(1.25);
}
/
.jacketa {
  transform: scale(0.8);   
}

Comment: Yours is identical to the original. In the image, yours is on the right, the left is the original version by itself. https://i.imgur.com/4HUNLiZ.png  None of the other codes come close.

Comment: No, using Photoshop you can see it https://imgur.com/a/8Z8ogjX

Comment: Really, use that technique: " if you look your monitor from below you could see it.". It's much more faster than using Photoshop ;)

Comment: This is the original https://jsfiddle.net/2qsgmrnf/ Yours is identical to it. Correct? This is yours. https://jsfiddle.net/2nLxw9y1/

Comment: They are not identical. The glow of your circle touches the top border of the canvas. The circle on the left is yours, the right is mine > https://imgur.com/aDqmPtl

Comment: The glow still touches the top border here? This code is mine: Code 1 https://jsfiddle.net/nftgb9j2/ //// This code is yours. Code 2 https://jsfiddle.net/zqvn07dm/ ///  Code 1 Left / Code 2 Right https://i.imgur.com/e9TGn5U.png

Comment: Yes, that's perfect

Comment: The glow still touches the top of the border in Code 1?

Comment: In Code 1 implementation, as is, no.